# How to setup JUnit tests for Glassfish Embeddable EJBContainer + EclipseLink JPA?

Tags: junit, glassfish, ejb, eclipselink, glassfish-embedded

I'm trying to use EJB 3.1 Embeddable EJBContainer on Glassfish 3.1 for integration
testing my EJB's. There's a classloading issue I can't figure out.

My ejbs are build into dum-ejb.jar. They use EclipseLink JPA. I also create EJB client jar dum-ejb-client.jar, while attempting to fight the classloading issues. Client jar contains the EJB interfaces, and Entity classes (which are usually parameters or returns values). Client jar also contains a lot of unneeded classes that could be dropped (but I don't see how it would solve the problem).

The problem is that since EclipseLink does bytecode weaving to the Entity classes, the Entity classes must not be in the classpath when the junit tests are run: http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/embedded-glassfish-and-weaving

I can do that and configure classpath so that dum-ejb.jar is not included. If I use EJBContainer so that I look up my service as a java.lang.Object and call it's methods via reflection, the test works. But of course, that's not how I want to write my tests.

Typical test would be like:

```
@Test
   public void testInEJBContainer() throws Exception {

       File ejbJarFile = new File("target/dum/dum-ejb.jar");

       Map props = new HashMap();
       props.put("org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.glassfish.instance.root",
               "target/classes/instance-root");
       props.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, new File[]{ejbJarFile});
       EJBContainer container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(props);

       CompanyService = (CompanyService)
container.getContext().lookup("java:global/dum/CompanyServiceImpl");
       log.info("result of findAll() " + service.findAll(false));
   }
```

How could I run the test if CompanyService interface, and returned Company Entity classes can not be in the classpath?

Even if dum-ejb.jar is not on classpath, and dum-ejb-client.jar is, EclipseLink weaving gets broken.

Isn't this exactly the typical use case for EJBContainer, shouldn't there be a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I ran into classloading problems since I was running the EJBContainer from maven ear project.

When I run it from the maven ejb project itself, there's no such issues and EJBContainer is easy to use.